# Solr: Using the Block Join Children Query Parser

Tags: java, solr, solrcloud

Currently I evaluate the Block Join Children Query Parser as described [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Parsers#OtherParsers-BlockJoinQueryParsers).

Therefore I have created the following collection:

```
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATE&name=nestedPerson&numShards=6"`
```

Then I have inserted these two documents:

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/nestedPerson/update?commitWithin=3000 -d '<add>
        <doc>
        <field name="id">p1</field>
        <field name="deceased">false</field>
        <doc>
            <field name="id">c1</field>
            <field name="firstName">Bob</field>
        </doc>
        </doc>
        <doc>
        <field name="id">p2</field>
        <field name="deceased">true</field>
        <doc>
            <field name="id">c2</field>
            <field name="firstName">Max</field>
        </doc>
        </doc>
    </add>'
```

Now I issue this query:

```
{!child of="id:p1"}firstName:Bob
```

Unfortunately this results in this error:

```
"msg": "Parent query yields document which is not matched by parents filter, docID=0",
```

How can the parent query (I guess that the part `id:p1` is meant) yield a document that is not matched by the filter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the Solr Wiki that you refer to again [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Parsers#OtherParsers-BlockJoinQueryParsers). Note the following:

`The syntax for this parser is: q={!child of=<allParents>}<someParents>. The parameter allParents is a filter that matches only parent documents`

In your example, the query is `{!child of="id:p1"}firstName:Bob`. The field `id` as used in`<allParents>`, but `id` is contained in both parent and child documents.

You need to introduce a field that only parent documents have, such as `<field name="content_type">parentDocument</field>` from the wiki. Once all parent documents (and only parent documents) have this field, you could submit the query as:

`q={!parent which="content_type:parentDocument"}firstName:Bob`

This would match child documents for `firstName:Bob` and return their parents. In a similar fashion, use `q={!child of=<allParents>}<someParents>` to match parent documents and return their children.

Comment: I have changed my document such that parent and child document have different fields: `<doc>
 <field name="id">1</field>
 <field name="pd">pd</field>
 <field name="deceased">false</field>
 <doc>
  <field name="id">2</field>
  <field name="cd">cd</field>
  <field name="firstName">Bob</field>
 </doc>
</doc>`. Unfortunately I still get the same error when I search for `{!child of=pd:pd}firstName:Bob`.

Comment: Now I have found my problem: The part of the query after the curly brackets is the query on the parent documents and not on the child documents (as the name child suggests). The name child indicates that it returns children. Thanks.

Comment: How should I change the query to get BOTH the matching child and its parent?