# Solr returning incorrect results when filtering child docuements

Tags: solr

I'm using Solr 5.4.0. I've imported some simple data with nested documents:

```
<doc>
  <field name="id">d1</field>
  <field name="content_type">parent_document</field>
  <doc>
    <field name="id">d2</field>  
    <field name="content_type">related_parent</field>
  </doc>
</doc>
<doc>
  <field name="id">d3</field>
  <field name="content_type">parent</field>
  <doc>
    <field name="id">d4</field>
    <field name="content_type">related_parent</field>
  </doc>
</doc>
<doc>
  <field name="id">d5</field>
  <field name="content_type">parent</field>
  <doc>
    <field name="id">d2</field>
    <field name="content_type">related_parent</field>
  </doc>
</doc>
```

The field definitions are:

```
<field name="id" type="string" multiValued="false" indexed="true" required="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="content_type" type="lowercase" omitTermFreqAndPositions="true" multiValued="false" indexed="true" required="true" stored="true"/>

<fieldType name="lowercase" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
<analyzer>
  <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

I need to find all documents which have d2 as a child document.
I using query:

```
q={!parent which=content_type:parent}id:d2
```

I would expect d5 as the result but instead I get:

```
"response": {
   "numFound": 1,
   "start": 0,
   "docs": [
     {
       "id": "d3",
       "content_type": "parent",
       "_version_": 1531507509621162000,
       "_root_": "d3"
     },
     {
       "id": "d5",
       "content_type": "parent",
       "_version_": 1531507848756854800,
       "_root_": "d5"
     }
   ]
 }
```

Why d3 is returned here? What condition should I add to this query to filter out d3?

Comment: did you find why it happened? I've seen something similar in 6.6, but in our case we took fiddler captures and all looked correct, but at least 1 out of 100 documents was affected by the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two things going on here:

1. As in my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/31952527/3229995 , the field "content_type" should only be present in parent documents. I had some inconsistent behavior in previous Solr versions with having the field "content_type" with some other value in child documents present, and I do not know if this problem has been resolved in the current version.
2. There are two documents with id="d2" in your dataset. In Solr, each document has a unique identifier, by default this is the id field. There cannot be two documents with the same unique identifier in your collection.

I would suggest to change both points accordingly for the block join query parser to work correctly.

Comment: ad 2, yes, I've changed the field names in my example code. In the real data, the field has other name, so it's not the cause of the error.

Comment: As per 1, only add the "content_type" field to your parent docs in the example. Does it work then?